# how to access virtual machine behind NAT from public network

Tags: virtual-machines, nat, nagios

I have a 1&1 hosting dedicated server (linux centos 5.x with plesk) (IP 74.208.98.x) and configured a nagiosxi virtual machine to run in NAT mode under VMware player 4.0. because i unable to use bridge mode where 1&1 security system sees MAC spoofing from Virtual machine and terminating my server to go OFFLINE.. only possiblity i can use is NAT mode.

I wanna know how i can communicate with nagiosXI VM from Internet. It would be better if i can able to map the nagiosxi internal IP with one of my subdomain. I do have a fixed static IP that i am thinking to use if possible such than NagiosXI VM wont rely on DHCP.

A little brief explanation would be greatful to me towards understanding the step i need to follow.

Comment: You need to provide more information!

Comment: What is 1&1? Why does it force you to do NAT? This would be better accomplished with bridged networking.

Comment: I don't think you understand how NAT works. The best you can do in this situation is to forward ports from the host node and access via the host address.

Comment: @JohnBritto, an Anonymous user just tried to add to this post. The quality of the edit was very low. If that was you please use the account you created (OpenID or the original computer w/ cookie) to edit your Question (I'ad also strongly suggest making sure your edit makes sense).

Comment: What do you mean by communicate?  Do you want to send alerts onto the Internet?  View the Nagios GUI over the Internet?  Or, perform some check across the Internet?  Each of these would require different solutions.